# How can I add a string to the first field of the output with awk?

Tags: linux, awk, sed, rhel, perl

The following script prints the output down:

```
/var/lib/ambari-server/resources/scripts/configs.sh get localhost c1 yarn-env
```

The output of the script:

```
 "yarn_log_dir_prefix" : "/var/log/hadoop-yarn",
 "yarn_pid_dir_prefix" : "/var/run/hadoop-yarn",
 "yarn_user" : "yarn",
 "yarn_user_nofile_limit" : "32768",
 "yarn_user_nproc_limit" : "65536"
```

I want to add with pipeline the awk or perl oneline linear, the **yarn-env** in the first field of output as the following: (expected results)

```
/var/lib/ambari-server/resources/scripts/configs.sh get localhost c1 yarn-env | awk ...


yarn-env  "yarn_log_dir_prefix" : "/var/log/hadoop-yarn",
yarn-env  "yarn_pid_dir_prefix" : "/var/run/hadoop-yarn",
yarn-env  "yarn_user" : "yarn",
yarn-env  "yarn_user_nofile_limit" : "32768",
yarn-env  "yarn_user_nproc_limit" : "65536"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/var/lib/ambari-server/resources/scripts/configs.sh get localhost c1 yarn-env |
awk '{ print "yarn-env", $0 }'
```

This short `awk` script will prepend the string `yarn-env` to each line of input from your command. The delimiter used is the `awk` variable `OFS` ("output field separator", a single space by default), so if you want a tab between the two, use

```
/var/lib/ambari-server/resources/scripts/configs.sh get localhost c1 yarn-env |
awk -vOFS="\t" '{ print "yarn-env", $0 }'
```

Alternatively, using `sed`:

```
/var/lib/ambari-server/resources/scripts/configs.sh get localhost c1 yarn-env |
sed 's/^/yarn-env /'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way with perl:

```
perl -pe 's/^/yarn_env /'
```

As you may know, TIMTOWTDI.